# Политика конфиденциальности для сайта использующего Instagram API

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, privacy

Вопрос не связан с программированием, просто запутался.
На данном моменте я нахожусь в Sandbox Mode, чтобы отправить свой сайт на проверку, я должен указать ссылку на Privacy Policy. Я хочу на сайте сделать сейчас этот раздел, но я никогда не писал политику конфиденциальности, есть ли образец как её заполнить? По сути я использую лишь один scope, я должен описать, зачем я беру у юзера информацию за этот scope? и обязательно ли писать эту политику на английском языке?

Answer (score 2):

Не хочу вас расстраивать, но Instagram отклоняет 99,9% всех приложений на review. На практике, как правило, одобряют только приложения, которые уже имеют успешный опыт работы с коммерческими API Facebook. Это их общая политика в отношении своего API, призванная резко ограничить количество сторонних разработчиков и перевести использование API в коммерческое русло.

Рекомендую смотреть в сторону Private API, на GitHub сейчас много хороших решений, которые позволяют делать практически любые запросы, доступные официальному приложению Instagram.

Comment: Почему нет решений для Facebook Private API?